# I want to create a command that deletes messages but the command doesnt work, discord,js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to create a command that clears messages but i dont know why its not working, when i type "-clear" in discord the expected message comes but when i try to type it with another number with the "-clear" command it doesnt clear any message or reply with anything. There is also no errors in the console.

Here is my code in my clear.js file:

```
module.exports = {
name: 'clear',
description: "clears messages",
async execute(message, args){

  if(!args[0]) return message.reply("**Enter the amunt of messages you would like to clear!**");
  if(isNaN(args[0])) return message.reply("Please enter a number!");

  if(args[0] > 100) return message.reply("You cannot delete more than 100 messages!")
  if(args[0] < 1) return message.reply("That is not a valid number, you must delete atleast 1 message!");

  await message.channel.messages.fetch({limit: args[0]}).then(messages =>{
    message.channel.bulkDelete(messages)
  });
```

This is the code in my main file

```
if (command === 'clear'){
    client.commands.get('clear').execute(message,args)
```

Comment: I believe it has to do something with the way you defined execute. Try `await client.commands.get('clear').execute(message,args)`

Comment: Im am getting an error when i use 'await' :             await client.commands.get('clear').execute(message,args);
        ^^^^^
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Comment: well, then declare the function where you call the script also async. Without any code this is all the help I can provide

Comment: i have provided all the code in the question let me know if you need any other code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason my code wasnt working was because of a mistake i made in the main file

```
 const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split("/ +/");
```

At the end i have put quotation marks and those are not suppose to be there, so basically the code should look like this:

```
 const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
```

Answer (score 0):

You used bulkDelete the wrong way, it should be written as this:

```
message.channel.bulkDelete(args[0]);
```

Make sure the value of args[0] is actually a number of messages you want to delete and not "clear"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you're using `then()` in

```js
await message.channel.messages.fetch({limit: args[0]}).then(messages =>{
    message.channel.bulkDelete(messages)
  });
```

you are using `messages` that may not be able to finish the `fetch()` function, so it may have no items in it. You can avoid this, as [brmbi suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69016709/10301322) by using `bulkDelete(numberOfMessageToDelete)`, that is, as the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=bulkDelete) explain, giving to the function the number of messages to delete.

So, you can have something like:

```js
message.channel.bulkDelete(args[0]);
```

Besides that, you have to consider when using `bulkDelete()`, that:

> Bulk deletes given messages that are newer than two weeks.

In case you're wondering to delete older than two weeks, you can just use `bulkDelete()` as follow:

```js
message.channel.bulkDelete(args[0], true);
```

Comment: it still doesnt clear messages, i believe it has something to do with the way i executed the command, when i type -clear it says i need to mention a number, but when i type -clear with a number in front it says nothing and no error, so i think it only responds to -clear because the the command is only executed when -clear is written. I am new to coding so sorry if this doesnt make sense

Comment: I've tried to replicate the issue with my bot, and it works fine to me. Maybe it's a problem with `message` and `args` when you're calling `client.commands.get('clear').execute(message,args)`? Try to `console.log(\`${typeof(message)} - ${typeof(args[0])}\`);` and tell me if there is something wrong

Comment: Reading again your comment, it's not clear to me when you're saying
"I think it only responds to -clear because the the command is only executed when -clear is written"
are you typing `-clear x` or `-clear` and after the command is executed you insert the number?